# Outlook Fails to Load Template Images

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

The following code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim sName As String
  Dim otlQuote As Outlook.MailItem

  If InStr(Item.Subject, "SOQ") <> 0 Then
    sName = Item.Body
    Set otlQuote = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Outlook Templates\Quotations.oft")
    Item.HTMLBody = otlQuote.HTMLBody
    Item.HTMLBody = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, "Good day ", "Good day " & sName)
  End If
End Sub
```

Produces images that look like this:

[image: FailedImage]

I know why this is happening, it’s because the image is linked and not embedded into the file, but is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are only copying the message body, but not the attachments (which probably contain the images).